# How to get from Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics an Edge loading failed message?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, diagnostics

I am doing a program to get  http events from Edge tabs using the UWP [windows.web.http.diagnostics api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.diagnostics). I have achieved to receive the http events from Edge. For instance, when an http request is send (navigate to another page in the browser) I receive a [requestSent event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.diagnostics.httpdiagnosticprovider#Windows_Web_Http_Diagnostics_HttpDiagnosticProvider_RequestSent). So far so good.

Now I want to get a **loading failed message**, but I do not know how to force it in Edge, and which messages I should receive from the http.diagnostics API.

Somebody could give me any hint about how to generate this loading fail messages in Edge and what I will receive from the windows.web.http.diagnostics api?

Thank you!!

**Edit (11-Aug-2017):**

After some investigation it seems that in the current version of windows.web.http.diagnostics API this information is not being provided by the events. So it is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean the Edge is Edge browser or the WebView that uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content?

Comment: I mean the Edge browser itself. With UWP, I search for all the Edge processes and I listen to all the http traffic of these processes using the  [windows.web.http.diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.diagnostics) api.